# extract CN from client's certificate on nginx-ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using kubernetes/ingress-nginx. 
Task is to extract CN field from client's certificate using nginx ingress. I was searching for a while and found a solution:

```
   map  $ssl_client_s_dn  $ssl_client_s_dn_cn {
    default "";
    ~CN=(?<CN>[^/,\"]+) $CN;
  }
```

But I can't adapt this code for nginx ingress.That's what I currently have and it doesn't work.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/http-snippets: |
  map  $ssl_client_s_dn  $ssl_client_s_dn_cn {
    default "";
    ~CN=(?<CN>[^/,\"]+) $CN;
  }
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  proxy_set_header Remote-User $ssl_client_s_dn_cn;
```

Probably someone faced with it and know how to adjust this properly, as I'm out of ideas.
If you know more elegant way to do it please share you knowledge here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of nginx are you using?

Comment: nginx version: nginx/1.17.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution,hope it may help someone:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/http-snippet: |
     map  $ssl_client_s_dn  $ssl_client_s_dn_cn {
       default "";
       ~CN=(?<CN>[^/,\"]+) $CN;
     };

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet: |
     proxy_set_header REMOTE-USER $ssl_client_s_dn_cn;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution just want to mention here, that I run `nginx-ingress-1.36.3` and I needed some adjustments. There is no annotation for `http-snippet` anymore. I moved the map module to the `ConfigMap` to adjust my Nginx configuration and now everything is working fine https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#http-snippet